# Whats wrong with this HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was referring the code in js fiddle:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/tr3Lmsbj/) which works fine

```
!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<style>
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 120px;
    border: thin solid #000;
    margin: 0.25em;
}
.item .title {
    font-weight: bold;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.item {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
#top {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FFF;
}
#top h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#search {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.25em;
    text-align: center;
}
#results {
    padding-top: 90px;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon:before {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #4466DD;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top">
    <h1>Programming Languages</h1>
    <input type="text" id="search" value="" placeholder="Search..." />
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
<script>..................
```

But when I wrote the same code and hosted in this website (http://indianwaterpurifiers.online/) see the view source, the grid is not rendering in the browser.

What's wrong with the HTML file?

Comment: The W3C has a [validation utility](https://validator.w3.org/) that should be your first line of defense if you think you're working with malformed HTML. I'd recommend going to your site, copying the HTML into the validator, and seeing what errors are thrown.

Comment: just take the source of the website http://indianwaterpurifiers.online/ please

Comment: "This includes CSS javascript html" isn't HTML. HTML follows the basic format of <tag attr="value">content</tag>. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML

Comment: The question is not clear but from first look your mentioned website is throwing a console error saying it's missing JQuery. Maybe add a jquery reference to it?

Comment: I checked out the content of the website. jQuery wasn't loaded into the JS script. jQuery isn't part of JavaScript. You need a <script> tag to load it.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. Did you script include jQuery to your web page?

Comment: </style>
</head>
<body>
its closed

Comment: need to include a jQuery CDN or local copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a site where you load [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/), but that is dependent on [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). Make sure you include that on the page before jQuery UI.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Included

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and it worked , thanks for the comments